# How are files saved on a live boot of Ubuntu? Is Casper rw even necessary?

Tags: partitioning, live-usb, persistence

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on a USB flash drive which I use on my chromebook. I created a persistent file (casper) and it's around 4GB. However, I can save files on the casper-rw volume OR a volume called "Computer", and they both keep the files after a reboot. I tested the flash drive on another computer (RUNNING UBUNTU 16.04) to be sure it wasn't saving the files on the chromebook SSD. Sure enough, the files saved on Computer/ubuntu/home/Pictures were still there, the files on Computer/ubuntu/home/Desktop were still there, and the files on casper-rw are still there. Did I even need to make the casper volume to store files? It seems like the usb boot is doing that anyway.

If it is indeed required and somehow the computer volume is on casper or something, how do I make casper larger? Thanks.

Edit: I see that casper-rw is found on Computer/media/ubuntu/casper-rw. The files I saved as a test are found in Computer/home/ubuntu/. I'm not sure if that helps the answer.

Comment: Yes it is necessary if u want a temporary hard disk of 4gb mounted along with ur bootable ubuntu on which your data is being saved everytime u shut down.. whereas making it only bootable without persistent mode will simply delete the temporary live session, Ubuntu just created

Comment: Are you saying that the reason the files on Computer/ubuntu/home are saved across reboots is because I made the casper file?

Comment: Yes..this Casper drive was created when u were dealing while making a bootable stick

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence. You need a casper-rw to save data. The file itself can be located on the flash drive, hard drive, or ssd.

Comment: How does this explain the fact that I can save in places that aren't the casper partition?

Answer (score 0):

You can write to other partitions in order to save files from a live system, but what you write to the root partition will vanish when you reboot or shutdown the computer. The root partition is in RAM (a temporary memory space). This means that you cannot install programs or tweak the system settings.

In order to do that you need a casper-rw file or even better, a casper-rw partition. If you want to be advanced, you can have a home-rw partition too.

The method is to *overlay* the live file system with the stored system of the casper-rw (and home-rw if available)

-o-

The tool ***mkusb*** can create persistent live systems of all current versions of Ubuntu and Ubuntu community flavours (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu) and Debian Jessie.

It creates a **casper-rw partition** for persistence automatically.

You can decide how much of the available drive space to use for persistence. The rest (of the available drive space) will be used for a **usbdata** partition, available also from Windows.

See these links

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

Comment: On the link you provided "mkusb will 'use the whole device', actually only the head end (size of the iso file), but the rest of the device is not available. mkusb simply clones the ISO 9660 file system with its content from the iso file. ". It (IMHO) contradicts with what you wrote " The rest (of the available drive space) will be used for a usbdata partition, available also from Windows." How do you merge these two pieces of info?

Comment: @Marisha, 1. When mkusb creates a live (live-only) drive it uses the robust cloning method. It works as you describe in your comment; 2.When mkusb creates a persistent live drive, it creates a partition table with 5 partitions, and one of them is a `casper-rw` partition, where the system stores data, so that they persist across shutdown and reboot; 3. With the new Ubuntu 19.10 you can actually **clone *and* have a `casper-rw`** partition behind the cloned image and get persistence. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/minp).